# Problem: To make default mongrel web server for rail 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

Solution : You have only one ruby version of ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
Problem Cause: Registry is still showing older version of RubyGems
Solution Path: Remove all old version of ruby & dependencies
(Note ensure to have all the back ups as your old apps on earlier ruby version which may not run after this solution)

Step 1: Go to command prompt & position at latest ruby 192 path
Step 2: gem cleanup (Select Y for all prompts)
Step 3: gem uninstall json
Step 4: gem install json
Step 5: Open user/app/GemFile and enter the line below under the line gem 'rails', '3.0.5' 
gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'
step 6: rails server
Will boot from Mongrel & Rails 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Problem: To make default mongrel web server for rail 3.0
Solution 2: You have only one ruby version of ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
Problem Cause: Registry is still showing older version of RubyGems
Solution Path: Remove all old version of ruby & dependencies
(Note ensure to have all teh back ups as your old apps on earlier ruby version may not run)

Step 1: Go to command prompt & position at latest ruby 192 path
Step 2: gem cleanup (Select Y for all prompts)
Step 3: gem uninstall json
Step 4: gem install json
Step 5: Open user/app/GemFile and enter the line below under the line gem 'rails', '3.0.5' 
gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'
step 6: rails server
Will boot from Mongrel & Rails 3.0.5